# Decimal property truncated on Applicationuser

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have an MVC application with entity framework database first approach. I have two tables where i store Latitude and Longitude as Decimale(12,9), one is table X and one is table AspnetUsers. For table X it's all ok, for AspnetUsers when i do a save, values are rounded to 2 decimal points. I'm almost sure it's Entity framework that does this, but i can't find anywhere ho to solve:
-EDMX present correct datatype/scale/precision
-Database tables have correct datatype/scale/precision
-Model for table X have Decimal? 
-Model for table AspnetUsers have Decimal?

here the confirm that EF use Decimal(18,2) on aspnetusers, because i can see it using sql profiler[image]

I think that i have to do something in IdentityModel.cs where i defined properties for ApplicationUser, anyone has ideas?

[image]

Comment: How you are getting values in `lat` and `lng`? from User Interface? is it sending correct values?

Comment: I get values from a form but when i set the values on the object's property it's all right, after doing savechanges() when i look to the record in database i see values rounded to only 2 digits